# Time to insert facts in the working memory increase based on the rule base size

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

I was performing some evaluation experiments in my system, checking the time taken to insert different (in number of rules) rule bases and number of the facts in the memory. Note: I'm not using persistance. Drools version: 6.3.0.Final.

Table - Rule base (RB), Time to insert (TTI), time in milliseconds.
[image: Rule base (RB) reading time, rule base size, and time to insert (TTI) facts in the working memory.]

Based on the table preseted above, I would like to know why the time to include the facts in the memory increase when the rule base size is increased?

I'm not expert in Drools.

Comment: Are you using persistence? That would be one culprit. The other thing is, that in the session, the left hand side of your rule (the when part) is evaluated at insertion time of the fact. So the more rules, the more eval, the more time.

Comment: I'm not using persistance. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, I am not 100% sure about this, but I read about a trick. Would you like to try it? In your rules, add another matching object, just any random object will do. This will cause ALL your rules to only evaluate true if that object is available. Now insert your 3/6/12k facts into your session. Do NOT insert that last object until the very end. That should cause your engine to evaluate false in O(1) for all facts, and then power-match all facts at the last extra-fact that enables your rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fact insertion, retraction and update result in instantaneous evaluation of conditions, as far as is possible with the given state of the network. It isn't merely the *number* of rules; it is the number of references of the fact's type(s) that matters.

You observe an increase less than O(N), N being the number of rules, which nicely fits the theory.

The number of 12,000 rules is quite extraordinary (unless you have invented rules just to test scalability). If they are real, and if you are worried about performance, you should revise the rule structure.

**Edit** due to OP's comment.

The "number of references of a fact's type" is the number of times a certain class (= type) occurs in a pattern. In your examples

```
rule x when
$spec1 : Specification ( )
$spec2 : Specification ( $spec1.id ==2, id == 3, value > $spec1.value )

rule "x+1" when
$spec1 : Specification ( )
$spec2 : Specification ( $spec1.id ==3, id == 4, value > $spec1.value )
```

You have 2 rules but 4 references to `Specification`. This is bound to create a more complex network in the Engine. Also, a constraint depending *exclusively* on data in the *first* pattern (`$spec1.id ==X`) but occurring in the *second* pattern is almost certainly an anti-pattern.

Using poor constructs like these, there's virtually no limit for slowing down a RBS, not just Drools. Apparently you are indeed just testing scalability. Sticking to well-written rules might give you more conclusive results.